# Binding ngModel of custom form control (ControlValueAccessor) always sets form to dirty state

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a very simple custom form control.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'text-input',
    template: '<input [(ngModel)]="value" />',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => TextInputComponent),
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class TextInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    private _value: any;

    get value(): any { return this._value; }
    set value(value: any) { return this.writeValue(value); }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== this._value) {
            this._value = value;
            this.onChange(value);
        }
    }

    onChange = (x: any) => { };
    onTouched = () => { };
    registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

But my problem is, when I use it in a (reactive) form just setting `[(ngModel)]` evaluates `form.dirty` to `true`, but if I use a normal input control everything works as expected.

[image]

```html
<h2>Hello {{text}}</h2>

<form #f="ngForm" >
    <text-input [(ngModel)]="text" name="text"></text-input>
</form>

Dirty: {{f.dirty}}

<form #f2="ngForm" >
    <input [(ngModel)]="text" name="text" />
</form>

Dirty: {{f2.dirty}}
```

Is there any problem with my implementation? How can I get my custom control to work in a way that `dirty` only gets set to true when an interaction happens?

Plunkr reproduction: https://plnkr.co/edit/FBGAR4uqwen7nfIvHRaC?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** After some more tinkering I finally found what I believe should be the correct implementation.

I can't believe that I simply never found a good explanation online how the `onChange` and `writeValue` functions correspond to the dirty/prestine state and how resets are handled.

As soon as you call `onChange` your control will be set to `dirty: true`. Calling `form.reset()` will reset this state but also call `writeValue` to set the new value. So **NEVER** call `onChange` in this method because it will break your states.

In my implementation I have a simple setter for my value in which I call `onChange` to actually set the right state, because the setter is only called by the input control in my template.

Your control can maybe have a more complex handling of how the value is actually changed, but as long as you actually call `onChange` if you want to reflect the change to the outside and you can set the value of your control with `writeValue` without changing the state everything will work fine.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'text-input',
    template: `<input [(ngModel)]="value"
                  (blur)="onTouched()" />`,
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => TextInputComponent),
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class TextInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    private _value: any;

    // NOTE: you could also just bind to a normal field without
    // getters and setters and call onChange from your template
    // e.g. from (ngModelChange) of the input control
    get value(): any { return this._value; }
    set value(value: any) {
        this.writeValue(value);
        this.onChange(value);
    }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== this._value) {
            this._value = value;
        }
    }

    onChange(x: any) { console.log(x); }
    onTouch() { };
    registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```